# Missing APOC procedure:

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have installed 3.3.5 and APOC 3.3.0.3. I'm trying to use the apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce procedure but when I invoke it, I see the following message:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I type RETURN apoc.version() in the Neo4j browser, I see "3.3.0.3". So it sounds like APOC is correctly installed. When I type call apoc.help('search') in the Neo4j browser though, I only 6 results.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a `NULL` value to `apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce()`, which the procedure does not expect.

Try passing a non-null address string, like this:

```
CALL apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce("1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC")
```

Also, calling `apoc.help('search')` would provide help on procedures/functions whose names contain the "search" substring -- which does not seem relevant. Try this, instead:

```
CALL apoc.help('apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce');
```